# serialobject.read() gives type error

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using a raspberry pi2 to read (in python) settings in my nexstar telescope. I connect by means of a serialcable USB-serial. The connection works (I can stear the telescope).

Now I'm trying to read a setting on the telescope and get a type error:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 449, in read
    buf = os.read(self.fd, size-len(read))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'
```

My code:

```
serialobject=serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSB0", 9600, timeout = 1)
print serialobject.read(chr(122))
```

The result should be something like: "12AB0500, 40000500#"

Can any of you help me understand what this python-noob is doing wrong an what i should do to correct this?

Answer (score 1):

The `serialobject.read()` method only takes integers; it indicates how many characters you want to read.

You are passing in a one-character string instead, that's not a valid argument.